# Salvage tuna marinated in pineapple

Tags: marinade, pineapple, tuna

I was experimenting with marinating tuna steaks in a pineapple/orange sauce and when I seared one, it had a mushy surface and overwhelming pineapple flavor. I still have a few steaks marinating. Can they be salvaged?

Comment: Aside - this would have worked well with Chicken.  I've broiled chicken in the contents of a can of Fanta with some peeled madarins floating around, and it tasted *fancy*

Comment: Every time I see this pop up in the "Hot Network Questions" list my brain reads it as "Savage tuna marinated in pineapple" - and I want the recipe!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No.

While you could get most of the pineapple flavor out of the tuna by soaking it in ice water for several hours, you couldn't restore the texture.  Pineapple contains a natural [meat tenderizer](https://www.bradleysmoker.com/blogs/articles-tenderize/is-pineapple-juice-a-meat-tenderizer) that has broken down the protein structure of the fish. Soaking out the juice won't firm it up.

I suggest mincing the fish with some hot sauce and using it for spicy tuna rolls.

Comment: Specifically ice water?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, shmosel.

Comment: Just wondering if cold water will do or if there's a reason to use ice.

Comment: @shmosel food safety.  If you soak for several hours, you need to keep the fish out of the danger zone.

Answer (score 9):

Pizza.

[image]

<sub>image from [FoodFromPortuagl.com](https://www.foodfromportugal.com/recipes/tuna-pineapple-pizza/)</sub>

Well, you're probably not going to get decent tuna steaks out of them at this point, so double-down on the pineapple, cut up or mince the steaks, and put them on a pizza. Mushiness and a pineapple flavour wouldn't be out of place on a pizza, and wouldn't dominate next to the tomato and cheese.  You could add some pineapple chunks too and anything else you fancy. Pizza is a good way to use up left-overs and failed experiments, as it is very forgiving.

Answer (score 2):

### Crumbs !

Literally, use a series of egg wash and dip into breadcrumbs/flour/spices/seasoning to give you a KFC-esque layer on the outside, then pan-fry it.  Seasoning will help thin the pineapple flavour.

If your steaks are thick, then you may want to halve them across the middle (thin them?) more like a minute steak.  This will allow more coating and surface area to give a more-solid outside texture, to overbear the mushiness.